# Is there a way to know what number of element is triggering an event?

Tags: html, jquery

ok, so I'm trying to figure out how can I get the exact number of a set of dinamically added inputs to DOM to fill them up later with data that comes from database in a modal,
so the logic is when user selects data from the modal, the chosen data will fill the input where the user is located..

Here's my code..

```html
var numeroDeInput = 0; 
// crea row con los inputs de materia prima $('#materiaPrima').click(function(e) { numeroDeInput = $('.material').length; var tableRow = `
<div class="rowCreated d-flex gap-2 my-2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Material" class="material form-control buscarMaterial" name="material[]" \>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Medida 1" readonly class=" medida_uno form-control" name="medida_uno[]" \>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Medida 2" readonly class=" medida_dos form-control" name="medida_dos[]" \>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Largo" id="largo" class="form-control calcular" name="largo[]" \>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Ancho" id="ancho" class="form-control calcular" name="ancho[]" \>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Alto" id="alto" class="form-control calcular" name="alto[]" \>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Precio" readonly class="precio form-control" name="precio[]" \>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Subtotal" step=".01" readonly class="subtotal form-control" name="subtotal[]" \>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger py-0 removeRow"><i class="bi bi-x fs-3"></i></button>
</div>` $('.tableBody').append(tableRow); console.log(numeroDeInput); });
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: `e.target` is the element the event was triggered from. You can read all the attributes from it. For example `e.target.getAttribute('placeholder')`. You also need to put the eventhandler on the elements you want to watch.

Comment: @MarkusZeller can you be more specific because I'm console.log the event target and can't find anything relevant to target the exact input that triggered the event I mean I'm trying to get the index number of the input that triggered the event

Comment: You receive the input element itself. If you want it's index, the easiest way is to put another attribute like `data-index="0"` on it.

Comment: but the input is dynamically added and they all have the same class, I'd have to add a counter to incremente the value of the index and I've already tried that, I'm trying to acces it's natural index, so when I delete one input the index don't change in the other inputs

Comment: Each `<input>` has unique `name` property.  If you really need find index of an element, you can use this: `index = [...myElement.parentElement.children].indexOf(myElement)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an eventlistener to every number input field. When triggered, just iterate through all number input fields and count the index up until it matches.

For demonstration purpose I added a info div which displays the info on clicking number fields.

I used vanilla Javascript, because I don't use jQuery anymore.

```js
const numberSelector = 'input[type="number"]';
const info = document.getElementById('info');
document.querySelectorAll(numberSelector).forEach(
        number => number.addEventListener('click', input => {
            let index = 0;
            const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(numberSelector);
            while (index < inputs.length) {
                if (inputs[index] === input.target) {
                    info.innerText = `Index: ${index} Placeholder: ${input.target.placeholder}`;
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }
        })
);
```

```html
<div class="rowCreated d-flex gap-2 my-2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Material" class="material form-control buscarMaterial" name="material[]" \>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Medida 1" readonly class=" medida_uno form-control" name="medida_uno[]" \>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Medida 2" readonly class=" medida_dos form-control" name="medida_dos[]" \>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Largo" id="largo" class="form-control calcular" name="largo[]" \>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Ancho" id="ancho" class="form-control calcular" name="ancho[]" \>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Alto" id="alto" class="form-control calcular" name="alto[]" \>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Precio" readonly class="precio form-control" name="precio[]" \>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Subtotal" step=".01" readonly class="subtotal form-control" name="subtotal[]" \>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger py-0 removeRow"><i class="bi bi-x fs-3"></i></button>
    <div id="info"></div>
</div>
```